# Ошибка phpmyadmin: " Хранилище конфигурации phpMyAdmin не полностью настроено, некоторые расширенные функции были отключены"

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, расширения

Добрый день. Настраиваю дополнительные возможности phpmyadmin. Появилась ошибка:

> Хранилище конфигурации phpMyAdmin не полностью настроено, некоторые расширенные функции были отключены

Версии:
phpmyadmin 4.7.5
MySQL 5.6
Apach 2.4
PHP: 5.6.3
Работаю по Windows7 X64

1. Создал пользователя pma, дал ему глобальные привилегии(см. скрин).
   [image: Привилегии пользователя]
2. Cоздал базу данных phpmyadmin, импортировал файл create_tables.sql из 
   phpMyAdmin\sql, а потом файл upgrade_tables_4_7_0+.sql(как сказано в 
   инструкции к phpmyadmin)
3. Создал файл config.inc.php, вот что внутри:
   [image: Внутренности файла]

После этого и появилась ошибка. Как можно исправить и правильно подключить расширения?

Answer (score 1):

1) Импортируйте файл /scripts/create_tables.sql находящийся в
    phpMyAdmin.

2) Добавьте в конфигурационный файл config.inc.php
        строку:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
```

3) Очистите куки браузера и войдите в phpMyAdmin.

Инфу взял от сюду https://forum.php-myadmin.ru/viewtopic.php?id=2213

Comment: Проблема в том, что нет такой папки. Файл create_tables.sql есть в папке /sql/create_tables.sql

Импортировал файл из папки sql, но проблему это не решает